# How to find the sum of average in file handling

Tags: python

So..I need some help for this project. I'm starting to learn a bit about python and our discussion is about File Handling. I made the correct execution but the problem here is that I need to find the sum and the average of the given loop.

```
def num3():
    ifile = open(r'sales.txt','w')
    no_days = 7
    for count in range(1, no_days+1):
         print('List of Sales in Php')
         sales = float(input('Day' +str(count)+ ':\tPhp'))
         ifile.write(str(sales)+'\n')
         
   ifile.close()
num3()
```

Comment: Add up all the inputs, and divide by the count.

Comment: Initialize a variable `total` to `0`, do `total += sales` to get the sum.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def num3():
    with open('sales.txt','w') as fp:
        no_days = 7
        print('List of Sales in Php')
        total = 0
        for count in range(1, no_days+1):
            sales = float(input('Day' +str(count)+ ':'))
            total += sales
        total = total
        average = total/no_days
        fp.write(f'Total Value: {total}\nAverage Value: {average}')
        
    
num3()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the appreciated help. I'm still learning into python but I'm in 2nd year so this would help me a lot.

Comment: Good, happy learning. Would you mind accept the answer if my solution worked for you.

Comment: So i tried using the exact same code just like you did, but the problem is that the ifile.write() line had an invalid syntax error

Comment: Make sure you are using python version 3+

Comment: I use Python 3.8.4

Comment: try my edited snippet

Comment: I made a mistake, I forgot to put a double comma on the total so that's why it didn't work at first.

Answer (score 0):

you need to accomulate the sales in a sperate variable. and then divide it by no_days:

```
ifile = open(r'`enter code here`sales.txt', 'w')
no_days = 7
total_sales = 0
for count in range(1, no_days + 1):
    print('List of Sales in Php')
    sales = float(input('Day' + str(count) + ':\tPhp'))
    total_sales += sales
    ifile.write(str(sales) + '\n')
ifile.close()

print(f"sum={total_sales}")
print(f"average={total_sales / no_days}")
```

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for answering my problem. I'm already in 2nd year so I need some help since our topic is about file handling so let me try to use this code